# Can I replace systemJS by webpack with angular2

Tags: angular, webpack, systemjs

I understood that systemJS and webpack are doing the same.
So I would like to replace systemJS by webpack but when I'm removing the system.js script reference in my html page I get the following error:

```
angular2.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

Does it means that angular2 is using SystemJS as module loader without the possibility to replace it by another one?

Comment: It means that the bundles you get in node_modules are built with SystemJS builder. If you want to use WebPack you can take a look at this [repository](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) and check [Overview.md](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/docs/bundles/overview.md#browserify--jspm--rollup--webpack-users)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

There are few [**examples & tutorials**](https://www.google.com/?q=using%20webpack%20with%20angular).

For example:

- https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack
- https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter
- https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-es6-starter (suggested by [@blacksonic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1725325/blacksonic))

Comment: I would extend the list with a Javascript alternative also https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-es6-starter

Comment: Recently converted a project from SystemJS + Gulp to angular2-webpack-starter. A month later still very happy about it.

Answer (score 0):

remove the following script on your index.html

```
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
or
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
```

then go ahead and add webpack