# Angular2 QuickStart SystemJS To Webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I'm trying enable wepback for angular2. 
I loaded QuickStart app and tried change systemJS to webpack as it done in
[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9w5hFit5rM)

When I run webpage I got an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

Does someone know the reason of issue and how fix it?

Comment: Please put the script tags you are including in your HTML. Need to see it.

Comment: <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="dist/main.bundle.js"></script>

Comment: Can you put a plunker. You still have the system call in script

Comment: Are you using webpack 1 or webpack 2? webpack 1 doesn't support SystemJS semantics out of box. Maybe that's it?

Comment: I'm using 1.12.14. I have resolved the issue just start from beginning with min configuration.

Comment: Have you seen this page? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313019/can-i-replace-systemjs-by-webpack-with-angular2